# With rails before_action how can you protect from malicious users for create / update / edit and delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The rails before action seems useful for setting a variable shared by a number of actions in a controller.

But isn't the default implementation of the set_post that we see commonly on tutorials etc open to an attack by a malicious user?

If we take a controller like this:

```
PostsController < Application Controller
  before_action :set_post , only: [:show,:create,:update]

  def show
  ...
  end

  def create
  ...
  end

  def update
  ...
  end

  private
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When a user is presented the opportunity to update a post for example the form would be generated for them, and on post, params[:id] would contain the ID of the appropiate post - probably owned by the current_user.

However, it would not be difficult for a malicious user to alter the posted :id variable to allow them to actually end up setting the @post variable in the controller, to represent a different post, rather than the original being updated.

I could see this being safer:

```
private
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if(@post.user_id != current_user.id)
   redirect_to homepage, alert: "you can edit your own posts"
  end
end
```

However - that would stop other users viewing other people's posts! So how and where should this kind of check be performed to ensure that only the owner of a particular post can update / edit it. Is that something for the update controller action to handle itself with a check like this :

```
def update
  if @post.user_id != current_user.id
    redirect_to homepage, alert: "you can edit your own posts"
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: For policies logic, you can use pundit gem or cancancan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, and I actually see that security issue being made very often by newbie Rails programmers. They just generate scaffolds and don't change things to their needs.

I'm using something like the following in my controllers:

```
before_action :set_post
before_action :check_post_ownership, except: :show

private

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def check_post_ownership
  redirect_to homepage, alert: "..." unless @post.user_id == current_user.id
end
```

Comment: Ok thats great to know that other people are making these kinds of checks.

Comment: filters - instead of before_action ?

Comment: `before_action` is actually better, I will change my answer. No big deal, just a relatively recent trends in naming. Both are doing completely the same thing.